# Shopify: how to add a class depending on collection

Tags: collections, filtering, shopify, liquid

On a clients homepage they want 'all the products' listed with a load more button at the bottom.

There are four categories and each has a different color associated. I want to pull in all the products by date listed order and apply a class to the product depending on the category.

Currently I have

```
{% assign collection = collections.all %}
{% for product in collection.products %}
{% if collection.handle == 'clothing' %}
  <div class="theme-red overview-item">
{% elsif collection.handle == 'pictures' %}
  <div class="theme-green overview-item">
{% elsif collection.handle == 'posters' %}
  <div class="theme-blue overview-item">
{% elsif collection.handle == 'other' %}
  <div class="theme-beige overview-item">
{% else %}
  <div class="theme-none overview-item">
{% endif %}  
  ...
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

This is currently picking up as theme-none and that's because I'm calling collections.all?

How do I get all the products shown regardless of a collection and then apply do something as per the if/else statements like above.

Any ideas, I've tried to see if product.collections, collection.all_types with no happiness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're getting `theme-none` is because your if statement checks if the collection's handle is 'clothing', 'pictures', etc. but you've set the collection to `collections.all` so it's never going to match any of those conditions.

What you want to do instead is check if the current product is within one of those collections. For example:

```
{% assign collection = collections.all %}

{% for product in collection.products %}
  {% for c in product.collections %}
    {% if c.handle == 'clothing' %}
      {% assign theme = "red" %}
    {% elsif c.handle == 'pictures' %}
      {% assign theme = "green" %}
    {% elsif c.handle == 'posters' %}
      {% assign theme = "blue" %}
    {% elsif c.handle == 'other' %}
      {% assign theme = "beige" %}
    {% else %}
      {% assign theme = "none" %}
    {% endif %}  
  {% endfor %}

  <div class="theme-{{ theme }} overview-item">
    ...
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```